# Check if string can be mutated in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, constants

Say I have this function:

```
void f(char *s) {
    s[0] = 'x';
}
```

This function will sometimes cause errors and sometimes not. For example,

```
char *s = "test";
f(s); // Error

char t[] = "test";
f(t); // Success
```

Inside function `f`, is it possible to determine whether or not `s[0] = 'x';` will cause an error before doing it?

Comment: I don't believe that there's any portable way to do this. There might be some platform-specific techniques, though.

Comment: If someone chooses to use your function in such a way that exhibits undefined behavior, and your function is well-documented, that's on them.

Comment: Attempting to modify a `const` object results in undefined behaviour. Practically, that means you can't write a function that tests this. You can, however, get compile-time diagnostics by rigorously specifying which objects are `const`, so you never attempt to modify them or pass a `const` object to a function that modifies it.

Comment: @EOF: A string literal is not a `const` object. But modifying a string literal still has undefined behavior because of a special-case rule.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yes. It effectively has `const` semantics though.

Comment: @EOF: Not quite. This: `void func(char *not_const); func("literal");` is legal, even though it creates the potential for `func` to attempt to modify the string literal. Attempting to modify a string literal has undefined behavior. Attempting to modify a `const` object is (usually) a constraint violation, requiring a compile-time diagnostic.

Comment: @KeithThompson: You're right, but I'll put it like this: If `const` had been a part of C from the beginning, string literals would be `const` by default.

Comment: @EOF: Agreed (C++ is like that). But it's also important to understand that C string literals *aren't* `const `, and the pitfalls that can result from that if you're not careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The responsibility is on the caller to comply with requirements of the function that the argument be changeable, not the reverse.

```
const char *s = "test";     //  tell compiler s is immutable
f(s);                       //  compilation error since f() requires a non-const argument

char t[] = "test";
f(t); // Success
```

The only way to stop the compiler from rejecting f(s) in the above is to either remove the const from the declaration of s, or to cast the const'ness away.   Except in exceedingly rare circumstances, both are positive indicators of a problem.

Note:  it is an anomaly in the language that s can be declared without the const qualifier.   Get in the practice of using const where needed (e.g. when initialisating a pointer using a string literal).   A lot of program bugs are eliminated that way.

Answer (score 0):

Given the feedback I've received, It sounds like I should instead document whether or not the function requires its arguments to be mutable. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* f(char*);
void g(char*);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // s is immutable.
    char *s = "test";
    puts(f(s));

    // t is mutable.
    char t[] = "test";
    g(t);
    puts(t);
}

/*
 * Returns a copy of the given string where the first character is replaced with 'x'.
 * Parameter s must contain at least one character.
 */
char* f(char *s) {
    char *t = strdup(s);
    t[0] = 'x';
    return t;
}

/*
 * Replaces the first character of the given sting with 'x'.
 * Parameter s must contain at least one character and be mutable.
 */
void g(char *s) {
    s[0] = 'x';
}
```

Comment: "... document whether or not the function requires its arguments to be mutable..." Isn't it what `const` was invented for?

Comment: @c-smile In this example, function `g` requires parameter `s` to be non-constant. Is there a way to use `const` in this regard? If so, please post an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: The fact that your function `g()` modifies the string passed to it is all the documentation you need, here.

Comment: Using strdup() causes a memory leak, so is not exactly a viable solution to the problem.